# Deploying an Angular cli application on to Azure Service fabric

Tags: angular, angular-cli, azure-service-fabric

I have created a new Angular 4 application using Angular-cli and tried to deploy it on to Azure Service Fabric. I have used Visual Studio code to develop the application. I am able to create the bundles using ng build  but couldnt able to deploy  it on to Azure Service Fabric

Comment: What happens when you try to deploy? Error message? How do you deploy?

Comment: My question is how to deploy. I didn't find a tutorial to do it .

Comment: do you manage to deploy an angular cli app to service fabric?

Answer (score 1):

Ng build got nothing to do with Service Fabric stuff. 
If you want to host AngularJS app on Service Fabric then I guess all you need is a .Net Core project to serve static files and include all your AngularJS files in that project.

Comment: When I build my angular app in vs code, I get one index.html and 5 js files, which I have to deploy to service fabric